# How do i in mysql match all rows in table A with all rows in table b based on the nearest longitude and latitude point?

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

HI Guys first question here. I have simplified the table structure below to make it more apparent the problem. I am using mysql and I have no idea where to start with this one. I need to find the closest store for each of the customers in my database.

I have **table "A"** which contains the following

```
id primary key
customer - name of my customer
longitude
latitude
```

I have **table "B"**

```
id 
storeName - name of one of our branches
longitude
latitude
storeAddress - Address of store.
```

I wish to connect these two tables together so I get the following output

result set

```
A.id <- customers id from table
A.customerName
B.id relabelled as store_id
B.StoreName
B.longitude
B.latitude
B.storeAddress
```

Any ideas guys?

Thus when I run the query I get the nearest store for each of my customers in my database.

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't described what you have tried already to solve your problem, I suggest you read the articles in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) regarding asking questions, specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(     POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +     POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM TableName1  HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

This sql  gives you data sorted by nearest location and this question should help you with those two tables [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) . Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yay, science to the rescue!

Comment: Thanks for this. i have a couple of thousand old customers. so need to do this for a mail merge and as such do not want to do it a single query per customer. was hoping for an table a join tale b = output i can use then as new table.

Comment: I am on my phone right now so I am a little bit limited, but I will take a look at it as soon as get home :) .